# MySQL gives Unknown column error when forward engineering database from diagram

Tags: mysql, insert, database-diagrams, debugging

I have a MySQL EER diagram the I forward engineer into a database. I also use the forward engineer feature to generate insert statements for data automatically. After entering about 120 rows of data I forward engineered the database only for it to give an error:

```
ERROR: Error 1054: Unknown column 'XX' in 'field list'
SQL Code:
        INSERT INTO `mydb`.`Person` (`Person_ID`, `SSN`, `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `LastName`, `Gender`, `Race`, `MaritalStatus`, `Military`, `Note1`, `Note2`, `DOB`) VALUES (111, 'xxx-xx-xxxx', 'John', 'K', 'Smith', 'M', 'XX', 'XX', XX, 'Case_1', NULL, NULL)
```

I don't understand what the problem is; I'm using the forward engineer feature so none of the column names can be misspelled. Is this just a bug?

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0.31 if that helps. I know it isn't the latest version, but I downgraded because I encountered crashes while querying in the new version.

**Update**: J.D helpfully pointed out that the field didn't have quotes and from there I was able to find the problem. The Military field was a TinyInt and therefore wasn't being given quotation marks, but the data being inserted was a string; hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your issue is the following part in bold: 'XX', **XX**, 'Case_1' because it lacks single quotes. Not sure why a built-in auto-generation tool is doing that though. Maybe a bug in the old version of MySQL Workbench, that you're using.

Comment: Thanks, nice catch.

Comment: Since there's hundreds of rows it's not really practical to fix each one by hand. Instead I'm gonna see if setting that field to null does the trick.

Comment: I appreciate the help

Comment: @SlowlySwift No problem, glad to help!